# How to update azerothcore-wotlk docker container

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, docker-container, azerothcore

I'm running Azerothcore-WOTLK in docker following the official [installation guide for AzerothCore using Docker containers](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker) and I'm wondering how I can update the Azerothcore build and how to apply database updates without losing character data.

To update the docker container I guess I should pull the latest code from Github and rebuild the containers using `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up`, but how do I make sure my character data survives the update?

To update the database I'm assuming that I should apply all the SQL updates found [here](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/data/sql/updates), but is the db_assembler.sh usable for the docker container and if it is, how do I use it? What is the procedure for backing up important parts of the database before any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: since 22 April 2021 the Docker system in AC has been reworked and there is a new (simplified) procedure to install and update it available at the official website.

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#how-to-keep-your-azerothcore-updated-with-the-latest-changes

---

**LEGACY ANSWER**

1. Stop your `worldserver` and `authserver` containers using `docker-compose stop CONTAINER_NAME`.

For example:

`docker-compose stop azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1`

To see the names of your containers use `docker ps`.

<s>As the [FAQ](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#faq) mentions, do NOT use `docker-compose down` which **destroyes** the containers instead of just stopping them.</s>

2. Update your sources to latest version (i.e. `git pull`)
3. Rebuild the sources using `./bin/acore-docker-build` (now replaced by `./acore.sh docker build`)
4. [Update your DB](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Update#3-update-the-database) as you would normally do.
5. Start your containers again with `docker-compose start`

More specifically, about the question related to the DB:

> but is the db_assembler.sh usable for the docker container and if it is, how do I use it? What is the procedure for backing up important parts of the database before any update?

there is no difference with the traditional setup. When you use Docker, your DB is running inside a docker container that holds the MySQL-server. So you can access, update, backup, etc... your database exactly the same way you would do if you installed MySQL-server directly on your host machine.

To access it, as the official guide says:

> Use root as user and 127.0.0.1 as default host. The default password of the root DB user will be "password".

Comment: Will acore-docker-build replace the existing containers?

Comment: @Jimmy `acore-docker-build` will generate the `worldserver` and `authserver` processes (located under `docker/*server/bin`) which will then be used by the docker containers to run