# Issues updating Docker Azerothcore latest release on Mint 20

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm running Azerothcore-WOLTK inside a Docker container. I wanted to update it (it was cloned back in December 2019). Following my question here: [How to properly Update Docker Azerothcore with customizations to both code (scripts), modules and database (added quests, vendors, items)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473553/how-to-properly-update-docker-azerothcore-with-customizations-to-both-code-scri)

Everything went fine and was compiled safely. The database was also updated using the bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh. script.

However, using docker-compose up showed some issues:

```
ac-worldserver_1  | /azeroth-server/bin/worldserver: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ac-database_1     | 2020-09-11 22:34:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
ac-authserver_1   | /azeroth-server/bin/authserver: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 246, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.25/containers/695d16e8329be5e8771606aabaec4754a63521ef14c37f8ef92f50e55c34dfc7/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "compose/cli/log_printer.py", line 233, in watch_events
  File "compose/container.py", line 215, in attach_log_stream
  File "compose/container.py", line 307, in attach
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 57, in attach
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 385, in _read_from_socket
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 296, in _get_raw_response_socket
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 248, in _raise_for_status
  File "site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
docker.errors.APIError: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("b'container 695d16e8329be5e8771606aabaec4754a63521ef14c37f8ef92f50e55c34dfc7 is restarting, wait until the container is running'")
```

While I can access the database using HeidiSQL from my Windows machine (and everything looks fine in there), it seems the actual worldserver and authserver fail and I get an exit code right there.

I checked both libmysqlclient and libncurses, and both are installed:

```
libncurses6 is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).
libmysqlclient21 is already the newest version (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
```

I tried to do the below a couple of times:

```
docker-compose down
./bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache
./bin/acore-docker-build
docker-compose up
```

But the results are not changing. Any pointers?

Please see below my docker and docker-compose versions:

```
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe 
docker-compose version 1.27.1, build 509cfb99
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AzerothCore's latest version is not compatible with either Linux Mint 19.2 or Linux Mint 20.

I tried everything, including wiping and re-installing from the source github and the problem was always the same.

I did try first on Mint 19.2 (before upgrading to 20 hoping it would solve it) and the latest version simply did not work.

Restoring my backup from the version I installed back in December 2019 works.

At this point, something changed to AC code between December 2019 and now that broke the Mint 19.2 / 20 support. After tens of hours trying, I have no other conclusion to draw.

To anyone who might have my problem: If you have mint 19.2/20 try to install a December 2019 release from the AzerothCore github. That should work.

o/

Comment: Just tested Linux Mint 20 "Ulyana" - Cinnamon (64-bit) with the latest Azerothcore version.(no mods) Was able to bring it up without any issues with docker: i see the default version are a little different then you listed above `Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0` `docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown` did you change your source list to use the docker community repo?

Comment: I think I just did the usual apt-get update command, I don't recall changing the source list for it. Though since you are on a slightly older version and it works, it's possible it's the newest Docker version I has on my machine the culprit. Interesting...