# How should you properly backup your local scripts before updating to a version that overwrites them?

Tags: git, azerothcore

Okay so recently I've been getting into learning some custom scripting for some encounters, which on an `git pull` are all being overwritten.
Is the best way to:

1. just make a raw copy of the src/ folder as a back up. Then re-apply them and copy the changes manually to my own custom scripts to match the reference.
2. `git stash` - > `git pull` -> `git stash pop`, then manually apply changes to my own custom scripts to match the reference.
3. Is there a way to make `git pull` skip specific directories/folders, as an example:

Specific folder or file that does not get pulled when you run a `git pull`

```
-> Northrend/AzjolNerub
-> Northrend/AzjolNerub/AzjolNerub/boss_anubarak.cpp
```

(e.g.) A week ago there were core renames to some functions which affected some of my custom boss scripts. from [#6910](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/6910). So if I want to solve that I do either of the ways to backup and then change the renames of the functions, in that case at least.

Yes, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473553/how-to-properly-update-docker-azerothcore-with-customizations-to-both-code-scri).

It's more of a question on to do it properly for the future and if there are other options of course (currently I'm doing #2)). I know it might be a stupid question, but I really want to see what SHOULD be done in such cases as a non experienced guy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR

The best way to backup your local scripts, or any work, is to commit them. Do so in a private branch so it's distinct from origin.

##### Details

When working on something like this, I like to create my own private branch where I commit my changes. When there's an upstream update, I fetch the updates from origin and then rebase my branch onto the tip of the parent branch on origin. That way, my local changes live in commits with all the benefits that brings. And I typically go one step further: I have a private or personal fork/repo where I push that private branch, so it doesn't only exist in my sandbox, and I have backups on a different machine.

With the case you describe where core renames affected your code, I'd chose to merge the branch from origin into mine, rather than rebase, and then fix the code in my branch to make it compatible with the core renames. That way, I'd be keeping a history if my local work with respect to different versions of the origin.

Comment: Thanks you, much appreciated!